# Nat iptables trying to access sql server behind a linux network

Tags: iptables, nat

I have been struggling for a while now and can't seem to get this right.

We have a server on the internet call it IRE We have a second server behind a linux network we Call it PUL

we have a external IP `xxx.xxx.xxx.118` where PUL is located the internal IP of the server PUL is `192.168.0.178`

we want to connect to the SQL on PUL from IRE

I have added the following rules to the iptables (ubuntu server)

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0:1 -p tcp --dport 15433 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.187:15433 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 15433 -i eth0:1 -j ACCEPT
```

I deleted but also tried adding `-d xxx.xxx.xxx.118` to resolve but nothing i add or change allow's IRE to see the database of PUL.

what steps can I take to get the server of IRE to see PUL?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have anything else on the network blocking the traffic?

Comment: You might need to add virtual server rules forwarding from your gateway to this database host. For example, just say you have  gateway is 192.168.0.1 with the .118 external IP. you may need to do the incoming NAT there, to forward port 15433 to PUL 192.168.0.178.    You didn't say what the 192...187 address is. That's not a public IP.  Are you using a VPN or GRE tunnel?

Comment: On which server are you forwarding traffic to PUL because your rule is forwarding to 187

Comment: Oh now I'm guessing 187 is a typo of 178.  That could be why its not working

Answer (score 0):

Usual situation would be like:

```
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy    | IRE 

     Internet

xxx.xxx.xxx.118  | GW (wlan) gateway/modem external ip
192.168.0.1        | GW (eth)  gateway/modem internal ip

      Internal 
192.168.0.178  |  PUL


At GW wlan / external, incoming interface (INPUT)
  -  You need to allow the port
      (Maybe even from specific source yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy IP only)
  - You need incoming port forwarding (NAT) to 192...178:14533

At GW wlan / external OUTPUT 
  -  You probably already have outgoing non specific port NAT

At PUL you may need another rule to allow port 14533
```

So unless your PUL server is the gateway to the internet itself,  you've likely got the rules in the wrong place. I'm assuming that's not the case as you said your SQL server is "behind".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments and advice I finally got it working, not sure how I missed it I removed all the rules and only added this line:
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d xxx.xxx.xxx.118 --dport 15433 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.187
worked first time, its sorted now I have access to the SQL Server from the IRE server.

Again thank you